# Angular JS request to remote Sails server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, sails.js, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to make a request to a remote server running with Sails JS (NodeJS) using AngularJS in the frontend and I'm getting this origin 'null' error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://remoteserver:1337/login/. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My request looks somethign like:

```
$http.post('http://remoteserver:1337/login/', { email: userData.email, password: userData.password});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to enable cors on your sales app. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You nead the server to enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing),

from Sails.js cors documentation (http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors)

> To allow cross-origin requests from any domain to any route in your app, simply enable allRoutes in config/cors.js:
>   `allRoutes: true`

and here is a brief explanation about what CORS is and why it is needed:

http://enable-cors.org/index.html